# Вывод запроса через UNION в разных столбцах с заголовками

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, всё очень просто -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aid FROM u0148905_jks.applies WHERE state = 'Новое'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS bid FROM themes
```

Но он выводит:

```
COUNT(*)
    234
    432
```

А должен:

```
aid    bid
234    432
```

Что я сделал не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен `UNION`. А просто двойной запрос.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM u0148905_jks.applies 
    WHERE state = 'Новое'
) AS `aid`, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM themes
) as `bid`
```